# Change SSIS protection level for Project in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Shell and I have had to change my ProtectionLevel to 'DontSaveSensitive' mid project.

Now I get an error: Basic Checks.dtsx has a different ProtectionLevel than the project.

However, there is nowhere in the Project properties that I can see where the ProtectionLevel can be changed to match. All searches seem to indicate this is easy in VS 2012 but can't find any info for VS 2010

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different places where you can set ProtectionLevel.
First place is properties pane of a package, second place is properties pane of entire project (right click on a project and you will find it under Common Properties). Ensure that you have the same setting in both places.